# live update check for updates by match_id

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to create a script which update match results and live_in if it changes in the json file. The json file is dynamic and change all the time. At the moment it only adds and deletes new matches, which i'm doing by comparing the match_id's. This i'm doing in below code:

```
if (lastId) {
  match = match.filter(
    function(match) {
      return match.id > lastId;
    });
 }
```

Beside that i've created a snippet of my code which include the structure of the JSON script. My question is then how can i make it update the score and live_in if it changes in the JSON script?

http://plnkr.co/edit/fqcNfLtugI24KqZkXXvi?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given I understood you correctly: You need to distribute `match.id` to each `div.result-date` and `span.result-match-score`.

For instance:

```
<div class="result-date" id="result-date-id-1">...</div>
<span class="result-match-score" id="result-score1-id-1">...</span>
<span class="result-match-score" id="result-score2-id-1">...</span>
```

Then you can directly query these elements with the `match.id`:

```
$('div#result-date-id-1').html(...);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4x7c692k/1/

Comment: I've added mtach_id to in the matchedHtml function. However i'm not quite sure how to directly query elements in my case. have updated http://plnkr.co/edit/16FCjE1I2CCKKmhEpGAm?p=preview

Comment: Hm, it is difficult to test, since Plunkr reloads the whole script when I change something in the `data.json` file. Also I'm not completely into what you're doing. But when I understood you correctly, thats how I would do it: 1) On first load, build the HTML content. 2) In your `setTimeout` handler (`getMatches()`) get the whole JSON and use the `match.id` to iterate through all relevant HTML elements (`div#result-date-id-X`, `span#result-match-score1-id-X`, ...) and update its data.

Comment: Hmm i'm not quite into Jquery and i've been struggling with this for some time, u seem to understand it correct. i'll accept the answer since it is correct, now just gonna figure out how to implement it :S

Comment: Where do you struggle exactly? You can select the elements by `$('div#result-date-id-...')` and `$('span#result-match-score1-id-...')`. Have a look at the jsFiddle example I posted above. I updated the example since it contained unnecessary and confusing stuff. :P

Comment: As you see in my new plnkr above i've set the match_id for each match however when i try to set the date it does not seem to add i've tried doing this:                ´$('#part-2').append(matchHtml(this, 1))
              $('div#match-date-id-' + match['live in'] + '').html('test');´ to query the live in to its match-date-id, but not seem to work proberly

Comment: Ok, I had a deeper look. You need to have two iterations. One starts at `if (match.length)` and creates the content. After that you need a second unconditioned iteration which walks over all the `match-ids` and updates the related content. Please have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sDPJ2XQKTMUgeaaB7Ekm?p=preview - Additionally you need to load your JSON from an external resource, since the live-update of Plunker makes it impossible to change it without reloading the whole script. Also I cleaned up your code a bit. It was quite hard to read. You should really care about your indention. ;)

Comment: ooh sorry did not see you changed url

Comment: Seem to work now :) however it does not add or delete matches which is not the JSON file anymore, do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: It is basically the same like updating. If you want to directly select a specific element in jQuery, one solution is to pass an `id` attribute to them, like we did to the `date` and `score` elements. With the `id` you can get it like `$('div#id')` or `$('span#id')` or whatever and then do what you need, like append, change, delete, etc. So in your case you need to give the `match.match_id` to `div.result-in-month` aswell, store the `match_id` in an array for instance and then iterate it aswell to see what needs to be removed.

Comment: So i've given the obj['match_id'] to the div.result-in-month. Then i need to store all match_id's in an array in the first iteration and then create a new iteration which does what with the array?